# sql stored procedure sub query error

Tags: sql

i am trying to write a stored procedure for user login with OUTPUT parameter but i get the following error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure userLogin_proc9, Line 7
Invalid column name 'count'.
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure userLogin_proc9, Line 7
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery 
 is not introduced with EXISTS
```

stored procedure :

```
create procedure userLogin_proc
@userName nvarchar(45),
@passCode nvarchar(20),
@userID int OUTPUT
as
begin 
if(select count userName,passCode from userLogin where userName=@userName 
and passCode =     @passCode) = 0
set @userID =0 
end
```

how this problem can be solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `count(*)` rather than `count userName,passCode`

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure userLogin_proc11, Line 7
Column 'userLogin.passCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
when i use count(*) this error happens :

Answer (score 1):

You could change your IF statement to

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT userName FROM userLogin WHERE userName=@userName AND passCode = @passCode)
    SET @userID = 0
```